# Use scanf instead of fgets and fputs in my program in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isPalindrome( char *str, int length )
{

   if ( length < 1 )
   {
      return 1; /* no more chars to compare, its a palindrome */
   }

   if ( str[0] == str[length-1] )            /* Are the two ends same? */
   {
      return isPalindrome( str+1, length-2 ); /* continue checking */
   }
   else
   {
      return 0;      /* comparison failed, not a palindrome */
   }
}

void strToUpper( char *src )
{
   /* convet to upper case any letter */
   while( ( *src = toupper( *src ) ) != '\0' )
   {
      ++src;
   }
}

int main( void )
{
   int result = 0;
   char str[40] = { '\0' };

   printf( "Please type the string to identify Palindrom or not: ", stdout );
   fflush( stdout );

   fgets( str, sizeof str, stdin );
   strToUpper( str );   /* make all letters the same for comparison */
   result = isPalindrome( str, ( strlen( str ) - 1 ) ); /* recursive starts here */

   if( result == 1 )
   {
      printf( "1" );
   }
   else
   {
      printf( "0" );
   }

   getchar();
   return 0;

 }
```

I wrote this code which identifies palidromes in C, but I want to use `scanf` instead of `fputs` or `fgets`, so I can understand the other way to solve this problem.

Comment: The `scanf` functions should never be used for anything.  Also, when you put spaces on the inside of your parentheses you make the baby Jesus cry.

Comment: Why are you so insistent on fixing your code when it clearly already works? This is the second question you've asked with this piece of code. Why not test it and see if it has any problems before you go trying to correct it?

Comment: @Zack - I'm glad to see someone agree with me about the parenthesis thing. I wince every time I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `fputs` and only a single call to `fgets` in this code.

The method of input here really don't affect "way to solve this problem". It's the same code - changing one line won't change lot. `scanf` not a safe function. You can do `scanf("%s", str)` but `fgets` is better and recommended. If you need to analyze string after `fgets`, you can use `sscanf`.

Comment: `scanf` is safe if used right, but doing so is trickier than introductory C tutorials often teach, and I hope you didn't plan on doing much in the way of error recovery if you get bad input.

Comment: And `scanf("%s", str)` reads a whitespace-delimited word, not a line.  If you want to learn how to use `scanf`, find a problem for which it's suited.

Comment: Thanx for all the advices but I am trying to make my code for the people to who are begineer in C, so they can learn easily.. Is there anything else should I change to it to make it more simple?????

Comment: Well, you could stop using `printf` -- all three calls are incorrect, albeit in two different ways.  The use of `getchar` at the end of the program is also a bad practice.  The initialization of `str` is unnecessary.  And if you're going to go with open curly braces on their own lines, then you should omit the braces entirely around single-statement blocks.

Comment: Also, recursion is a notoriously difficult concept for people new to *programming*.  If your audience is learning C having already mastered a higher-level language, that's not a problem, but if you're teaching C to people new to programming, (a) that's a bad idea in itself, (b) you might want to consider changing `isPalindrome` to use iteration instead.